# How to check if a div class has been clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to check if a div class element has been clicked.Is there a way in Javascript. I have a conditional statement which checked whether a style has certain attributes, but there is no way I know of checking whether a div class in that conditional statement has been clicked...

Here's my code so far:

```
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("roll")[0];
let b = document.getElementsByClassName("effect")[0];

a.onclick = function(){
    b.setAttribute('style','border-right:4px solid #aa2e27')
}

a.onmouseover = function(){
    if(b.hasAttribute('style','border-right:none') && a.onclick.value == "true"){
        b.setAttribute('style','border-right:4px solid #aa2e27');
    }
}
```

As you can see, the if condition takes place on mouseover event. Is there a way to check this? (what I entered on mouseover doesnt trigger)

Comment: Is this a simplification of your real problem? Because that code adds the "style" attribute when `a` is clicked, or - when hovered - if it *hasn't* been clicked it adds the same style; and the `mouseover` event will always fire before before the click event since to click the element the pointer has to be over the element (triggering the `mouseover`). Obviously this is somewhat different if the user is using keyboard navigation, and may present an accessibility issue. But, the reason I ask if it's a simplification is that the functionality, and checks, don't make sense to me.

Comment: Changed it, David, but its not the right code anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a  element with a specific class has been clicked, you can use an event listener on that element and update a variable when the click event occurs. Here's an example:

```js
let divElement = document.getElementsByClassName("roll")[0];
let isClicked = false;

divElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  isClicked = true;
  // Additional code to execute when the div is clicked
});

// You can then use the `isClicked` variable in your conditional statement
divElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if (b.hasAttribute("style", "border-right:none") && !isClicked) {
    b.setAttribute("style", "border-right:4px solid #aa2e27");
  }
});
```

In this code, we initialize the isClicked variable to false. When the  element with the "roll" class is clicked, we set isClicked to true. Then, in the mouseover event listener, we check if isClicked is false before applying the desired styling.

By using an event listener for the click event, you can capture the moment when the  is clicked and update the state accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This kinda works, but what is happening when the element hasAttribute none and the link isClicked (or has been) then when I take the mouse out, the border is still there...(I hope this makes sense!)

Comment: if you want to remove the border when the mouse is moved out of the element after it has been clicked, you can add another event listener for the `mouseout` event.


`divElement.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  if (!isClicked) {
    b.removeAttribute("style");
  }
});`

Comment: Hi Tony, what the ```a.mouseout``` function does now is it removes the style and overrides the first ```a.onclick``` function. So what happens is when I click the ```a``` link and move mouse out the style gets removed (when I want the style to be there). This is harder to explain than I thought.

Comment: Finally got it working!!! Learnt something from you today (the removeAttribute).Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable in the outer scope to track that like this:

```
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("roll")[0];
let b = document.getElementsByClassName("effect")[0];
let aClicked = false;

a.onclick = function(){
    b.setAttribute('style','border-right:4px solid #aa2e27');
    aClicked = true;
}

a.onmouseover = function(){
    if(b.hasAttribute('style','border-right:none') && aClicked){
        b.setAttribute('style','border-right:4px solid #aa2e27');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. just add an eventlistener and update the global variable.

```js
var clicked = "not clicked"
document.getElementById('amiclicked').addEventListener("click", function() {
  clicked = "clicked";
  console.log(clicked)
});



console.log(clicked)
```

```html
<div id='amiclicked'>
  click me
</div>
```